# What's best practice to easily reuse bunch of code in multiple view controllers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm rather new to programming and wondering about a certain (best) practice:

Let's assume we have an app with several view controllers. In our case, most of those need the functionality of alerting the user about certain circumstances, make use of an activity indicator or depend on other similar general functionality. So far I've learnt how to implement such methods but then just copied the whole bunch of code to each view controller when needed. Doing so, every view controller gets filled up with a lot of extra code. I know it's possible to make code kind of "global" by moving it to the top of a view controller, outside the class brackets. But as we need to ensure that certain subviews are added to the right view controllers when calling those methods I'm not sure yet what the best way to go - in general - would be.

Is there a commonly used practice that differs from my approach when defining such - let's say - alert behaviors (defining variable/constant and its needed methods) which are used in multiple view controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C provides two general ways of reusing code:

1. Inheriting a base class, and
2. Using a shared function.

The first case is straightforward: if you need a specific functionality in several view controllers, make a base view controller with the shared methods, and then derive your other view controllers from it:

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
-(void)sharedMethodOne;
-(void)sharedMethodTwo;
@end
@interface FirstViewController : BaseViewController
...
@end
@interface SecondViewController : BaseViewController
...
@end
@interface ThirdViewController : BaseViewController
...
@end
```

The second case can be implemented either as a helper class with class methods (i.e. with `+` instead of `-`) or with free-standing C functions.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm coding in Swift but I guess both ways are working in Swift as well, except there are no `-` and `+` I guess but I can definitely figure that out! So I could expect to find such base classes in almost every app project? Would you recommend me right from the beginning to try such inheriting wherever possible followed by some customization within the sub class (view controllers)? Or does it just make sense in certain cases as over all complexity can also increase?

Comment: @AlexeiS. Inheriting makes more sense when your view controllers share some structure (similar UI elements, similar references in the model, etc.) If you need to share only the behavior without necessarily sharing structure, using a helper class or free-standing functions in Swift would give you more flexibility - for example, if you need to share behavior among controllers that derive from different `UIViewController` bases (say, a table view controller and a collection view controller).

Comment: With Swift, the equivalent to `-` and `+` would be `func` and `class func` respectively. @dasblinkenlight makes a good point that there are good times to simply have a "free-standing" function in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You should look to see what could be moved from the controller level to the view level. It sounds like you're reusing a bunch of views so I would create subclasses of `UIView`s that can implement themselves. Then in the view controller you can handle when the views should appear and the data associated with them but you don't need to rewrite how to implement the views.